# Is there a difference between endorphins that are released while physical activity and sex/masturbation?

Tags: human-biology, theoretical-biology, sex, psychology

I observerd myself and I can identify two different types of "happines".

1. First - called by me - After Pleasure :

   Occurs AFTER (and last long) long activity that require from me engagement focus and effort  for example :

   - running 16KM
   - learning for an hour things that I think are worthwhile
   - reading book
   - generally any mental or physical activity
2. Second - called by me - During Pleasure

   Occurs DURING (and last short time) activity that DON'T require any engagement, focus or effort, for example :

   - masturbation
   - eating sweets
   - eating tasty things in general
   - having hot bathing time
   - watching funny videos/TV

I wonder is there any scientific distinction between those two states of my body and mind. And assuming that endorphins are the hormones are responsible for the "oh-good" state, are different kind of endorphins are released while taking this 2 different activities (like studying for 1hour and masturbation) ?

Thanks for an answer in advance.

Comment: What kind of difference? Concentration, type? Can you clarify this?

Comment: @Chris I just suspect there is a difference between endorphins that are released during this 2 activities since the "oh-good" state is longer in the first one, and shorter in the second, because one is released after Activity, and second During activity.

Comment: The title is a bit overspecific and thus confusing. I guess you're asking about short-term and long-term rewarding system action. If so, then yes, there's a whole lot of things that differ between these, them are actually two different modes of rewarding, involving different mediators and subsystems. I won't give you any direct references, but you can search for yourself: look for dophamine receptor types and their action, oxytocine and other mediators. The main plot is that "during" pleasure is related to passion while "after, long-term" is related to stability, ensurance and persistance.